# Excel - Looping through a cell and adding percentages based on keyword

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm looking at a cell with the following contents:

15%-Ice Cream; 45%-Potatoes; 45%-Potatoes

I need to loop through the cell and add the percentages associated with Potatoes, meaning the formula would put out 90%. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Have you looked at the SUMIF function?

Comment: When you say looking at a cell with that information, is it literally one cell with all of that or 3 cells that you want to get the total from?

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula that splits on the `;` and iterates the parts looking for a string that ends in `Potatoes`.  It then sums the percentages.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MID(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),FIND("-",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))+1,99) = "Potatoes")*LEFT(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)),FIND("-",TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",REPT(" ",99)),(ROW($A$1:INDEX(A:A,LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2,";",""))+1))-1)*99+1,99)))-1))
```

This will output `0.9` so format the cell as a percentage to get 90%

[image]

Comment: What if the OP needs to do it for rutabagas?  :-)